# Quando arrastar um objecto até um outro Enviar mensagem

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Estou criando um jogo onde para acertar a resposta tem de arrastar o objecto `Button` até o objecto `Panel1`

Ele já arrasta o objecto, mas falta enviar uma `MessegeBox` logo que o botão é arrastado até o `panel`.

```
public nivel2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    INIT();
}

private Point firstPoint = new Point();

public void INIT()
{
    button1.MouseDown += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        if (ee.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            firstPoint = Control.MousePosition;
        }
    };

    button1.MouseMove += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        if (ee.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point temp = Control.MousePosition; 
            Point res = new Point(firstPoint.X - temp.X, firstPoint.Y - temp.Y);
            button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X - res.X, button1.Location.Y - res.Y);
            firstPoint = temp;
        }
    };

    if (button1.Location.X== panel1.Location.X || button1.Location.Y == button1.Location.Y)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Parabens");
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve verificar se a posição do botão está dentro do panel. O seu if tá perto, mas a fórmula correta é:

```
var btnX = button1.Location.X;
var btnY = button1.Location.Y;
if (panel.Location.X <= btnX && (panel.Location.X  + panel.Width >= btnX + button.Location.Width) && panel.Location.Y <= btnY && (panel.Location.Y + panel.Height >= btnY + button1.Height)) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Parabéns");
}
```